# Python - Can't install modules on mac

Tags: python, module, installation

I've downloaded Beautiful Soup 4.3.2 and CD'ed to the right location on my disk. When I use 'python setup.py install' a load of lines run but then I get this problem:

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4': Permission denied

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your user doesn't have permissions, try to run as root (sudo).

Comment: It's asking for a password but not letting me type there. I'm the only user so it's strange I  don't have permission.

Comment: edited my permissions manually, sorted. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You will often have to use sudo on mac, eg sudo python ...

This has been asked multiple times though, try searching before asking.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, your limits of authority is lower a little to install the python.

First, you should change your users to root. commnad:`su root`

Second,execute commands to install python.

I hope this can help you.